# why $f_1=\pi_1(f)$ and $f_2=\pi_2(f)$.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two topological spaces. We define two projections on $T_1\times T_2$ by setting $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_2(x,y)=y$. Clearly $\pi_j:T_1\times T_2\to T_j$.

I have a lemma which I don't completely understand.

Lemma: A map $f=(f_1,f_2):T\to T_1\times T_2$ is continuous if and only if $f_1$ and $f_2$, i.e. $\pi_1(f)$ and $\pi_2(f)$ are continuous.

I don't understand why $f_1=\pi_1(f)$ and $f_2=\pi_2(f)$. Could somebody explain how this is derived.

Comment: just use the definition of $\pi_1$. take any $t\in T$. $f(t)=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$ so $(\pi_1\circ f)(t)=\pi_1(f_1(t),f_2(t))=f_1(t)$.  similar argument for $\pi_2$ and $f_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $\pi_1 \circ f$ and $\pi_2 \circ f$ are more standard and clearer.

For any $t$ in the domain: $(\pi_1 \circ f)(t) = \pi_1(f(t)) = \pi_1(f_1(t), f_2(t)) = f_1(t)$ so the equality of functions $\pi_1 \circ f = f_1$  then follows automatically by definition.